Julia HCubature incorrectly calculating integrals as divergence
I am running the following Julia code.
using HCubature

f(x) = 1 / (exp(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2) - 1)

c = 0
a = [c, c, c]
b = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

result, error = hcubature(f, a, b)

println("result = ", result)
println("error = ", error)

It returns
result = Inf
error = NaN

However, this 3-d integral is clearly converged at x=(0,0,0).
Why does HCubature have such a problem? And what should I do to get the correct result?
I change the variable c from 0 to 1e-8 and the program returns
result = 1.4994522443953553
error = 2.234083860406827e-8

But if I change it to 1e-9, the program returns Inf again.
Maybe HCubature cannot properly deal with the singularity.
What should I do to make it can deal with the singularity?
